# When Internet speed is low My Service taking long time get data, how to achieve timed out

Tags: objective-c, timeout

In my App I am using web Service to get data. In some cases(low speed internet) Svc is taking so long time. So if Svc time is marathon is 30 Sec then I want to stop execution and then show an alert message like  `Timed out try again later`. How to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSMutableURLRequest like the following with `timeoutInterval` to set the request time out limit.

```
NSString *urlString = @"your url string";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

send request with:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
                       {
                           if (data)
                           {
                              // process your result data here
                           }
                       }];
```